# Saving an Image

Tags: php, image, save

I have a picture url like this http://www.address.com/image.jpg

I want do dynamically save this image on my server

How can i achieve this using php

Thanks

Comment: You can use any file function on remote files as long as "allow_url_fopen" is active on php.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and saving it using [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). Something like:

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://www.address.com/image.jpg');
file_put_contents('image.jpg', $image);
```

You also might want look into [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to fetch the image; it should perform better than `file_get_contents()` (unless you compile curl with `--with-curlwrappers`)